# Mongodb Query does not work with string

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to get documents in the database that match the string but it does not work when i pass in the variable.

I have a string serviceString and serviceString = "test1", "test2", "test3"

```
        query = db.collection('Services').find({
            'Service': {
                $in: [serviceString]
            }
        });
```

This returns nothing from the DB BUT if I do this:

```
        query = db.collection('Services').find({
            'Service': {
                $in: ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
            }
        });
```

It works and returns what I need.

Do you know why its not working, I am thinking the string is putting commas in as a string.  Whats a way I can do this because the string is a input from a user so it can change so I cant hard code the variables in the query?

Comment: Try this `query = db.collection('Services').find({
            'Service': {
                $in: serviceString.split(',')
            }
        });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$in` is looking up for an array.

So, It's better to create an array of string you want to find.

`let serviceString = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];`

**Note :** You can also use var instead of let here

Then your query will look likes :

```
let serviceString = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
query = db.collection('Services').find({
       'Service': {
           $in: serviceString
      }
});
```

more information : https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html#special-query-operators

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what are you doing first you are passing a complete string

```
"test1","test2","test3"
```

Do something like this

```
var serviceString = ["test1","test2","test3"];
```

and then your query

```
   query = db.collection('Services').find({
            'Service': {
                $in: serviceString
            }
        });
```